# Converting char * to int with strtol only if it's a valid number

Tags: c, validation, strtol

I tried to convert `char*` to `int` with `strtol`:

```
long lnum;
int num;
char *end;

char * str ="3a";
lnum = strtol(str, &end, 10);

printf(" res = %d \n" , lnum);
```

This code prints `3`.

How can I know that the input is not only digits? I want this conversion to fail because `"3a"` contains an `'a'` character.

Comment: @user3121023 why end must to be `char **` and not `char* ` ?

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution that is on my mind right know is check if the end is \0, that means the string is emtpy, so all the original string was a number

Comment: why I can't  check `if (*end != NULL )` ?  end is `char **` so `*end` is `char *` , why I can't compare it with NULL ?

Comment: Yes you can compare with it, and i suggest to do it too, but a good string in C should end in "\0"

Answer (score 0):

you can compare *end with NULL

```
if (*end != NULL)
{
    printf("failed");
}
```

Comment: NULL is a pointer and should not be compared with a char.  `*end != '\0'` makes it explicit you are comparing to 0 byte at end of string, `*end != 0` or even just `*end` are fine too.

Comment: `end` is `char **` to `*end` is `char *`  , why I can't compare it with NULL ?

Comment: In computer programming, null is both a value and a pointer. Null is a built-in constant that has a value of zero. It is the same as the character 0 used to terminate strings in C. Null can also be the value of a pointer, so NULL is not only about pointers

Comment: @joifdoi: in your code, `end` is a pointer, you pass its address to `strtol`, which stores the address of the first character after the number in the source string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string to an `int` with overflow and syntax checking, you must use extra tests in the code:

- check for overfow
- check for extra characters
- check the result for int range

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <limit.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convert_str(const char *str) {
    long lnum;
    int num;
    char *end;

    errno = 0;
    lnum = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if (errno || *end != '\0' || lnum < INT_MIN || lnum > INT_MAX) {
        printf("invalid input: %s\n", input)
        return 0;
    } else {
        num = lnum;
        printf("res = %d\n" , num);
        return num;
    }
}
```